# How to pass a request to a different Django view? (Show summary before submitting)

Tags: django, forms, request, summary

I am trying to show the user a summary of a form before the form is submitted and saved to the server.

I have a form on `index.html` and within that form, I have this input button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Show summary" name="summary"/>
```

On the `summary.html` page, I have another input button within a dummy form. I use this input button to get the form data saved.

```
<input type="submit" value="Save to DB" name="save_db" />
```

Here are code snippets of my the methods in my `views`:

```
def index(request):
    form = JobForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if  form.is_valid():
            return summary(request)

    return render_to_response('index.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def summary(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        save_to_db(request) # The problem here is that this is a new request. I lost the previous request with all the data
        return render_to_response('thanks.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    xml = getxml(request) # form data is serialized
    return render_to_response('summary.html', {'xml': xml}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

From the above, I am able to get a summary of the form data. However, as the inline comment suggests, when I click the "Save to DB" submit button, the previous request with all the form data is lost.

I have looked into `Sessions` and I could not find a proper of doing the above. I also tried to pass the `request` as a parameter to the the summary page. However, I think this is not the right way of doing it.

I would appreciate your input!

Thanks.

Comment: Why bother like this. When the user hits `Show Summary` button make all the input field disable using some javascript and show the form to the user with the data they entered. Also change button name to `Save to DB` and then only redirect form to  required view.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/formtools/form-preview/

Comment: Thanks for the response. That seems to be a plausible solution. However, I actually reformat the input and I show them the input data in a nice xml. (The goal here is to generate an xml with data from a form.) I use a couple of 3rd-party JS libs to prettify the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Django [Form Preview](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/formtools/form-preview/)? Seems that is exactly you are looking for:

> Django comes with an optional “form preview” application that helps
>   automate the following workflow: “Display an HTML form, force a
>   preview, then do something with the submission.” To force a preview of
>   a form submission, all you have to do is write a short Python class.

Cheers!